# What is the probability of picking a card from a deck of cards that was split in half?

Tags: probability

Lets say you have a regular 52 card deck, you split it in half and you're presented one of the halves. What is the probability that the card you'll draw is the ace of spades for example?

This is kind of confusing me because the sample space/the half you're choosing from might not even have the aces of spaces if its in the other deck.

I thought of several answers, including 1/52, 1/26 but they all dont make sense because if the card isnt there.

Comment: Every card has the same probability of being drawn.  Since there are 52 cards, that common probability must be $1/52.$

Answer (score 2):

Lets say that A is the event that the ace of spades is presented to you, so that it is in the right half of the deck, `P(A) = 0.5`
Let's be B the event that you pick the ace of space in a deck of 52, `P(B) = 1/52`
Because the 2 event are not independent `P(A and B) = P(A)P(B|A)`
Therefore `P(A and B) = 0.5 * P(B|A)`
`P(B|A)` is the probability you pick the ace of spade if it is presented to you (half a deck) so `P(B|A) = 1/26`
Thus `P(A and B) = 0.5*1/26 = 1/52`

Comment: This confuses me because what if the card isnt in the half you have? How can it still be 1/52? How is there a probability for something that can never happen?

Comment: if the card is not in the half you have the probability you pick it is 0. If it is the probability you pick it is 1/26. But because the first event is "the card is in your half" and has a prob of 0.5, it gives 1/52 as showed above

Comment: basically the important part is to realize that the event are not independent. Thus if you can pick the card, it means it was presented to you in the first place

Answer (score 2):

The process of splitting the deck is irrelevant here. Assuming that the deck is randomly sorted to begin with, and you choose one card from the deck with seeing the card faces, then the probability of choosing the ace of spade is always 1/52. It doesn't matter what your process of choosing the card is --- you might just take the top card, or you could split the deck then choose randomly, or split the deck twice, or whatever --- it just doesn't matter and can't change the probability.
The fact is that all 52 cards are treated symmetrically, hence all must have the same probability of being selected.

Given your setup, you could display the probability using the law of total probability:

P(choose ace spades) =
P(choose ace spades | ace of spades is in my half of deck) x P(ace of spades is in my half of deck) +
P(choose ace spaces | ace of spades is not in my half of deck) x P(ace of spaces is not in my half of desk)
= 1/26 x 1/2 + 0 x 1/2
= 1/52.

which may clarify things, but this calculation is just for education purposes. It is already apparent from general principles what the answer must be without doing any calculations.

Comment: Exactly. (+1) One can actually take this further and think of splitting the deck in four, 13, 26 and ultimately 52 chunks to see this.